# Java accesing a file through mac os vs windows?

Tags: java, macos, filepath, porting

So I'm porting my application over to mac and I was just wondering if we had a shared file on our network would the line of code

```
File test = new File("\\\\networkdrive\\data\\testfile")
```

work? Or if not what would it have to be if a computer running mac had to accesss the same folder in the network drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not the same as Windows. I think you have to connect from the Finder to the network drive, and then the filesystem will appear under `/Volumes`. I don't think the Mac recognizes a UNC as a proper path.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you add quotes:

```
File test = new File("\\\\server\\share\\data\\testfile");
```

As for how to access a UNC Path on Mac, see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/how-can-i-open-windows-network-links-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: Oh I forget to add quotes when I wrote up the question. Ok thanks, so it should work right?